# Method to extract the overlapping cells from two 2D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, overlap

I have a 2D `numpy array` shown in blue in the image below and a smaller 2D `numpy array` shown in green:

[image: Large blue 2D array with smaller partly overlapping green 2D array. The overlap is shown in red with a black *X* in the center of the green array.]

I am looking for a general `numpy` method which will extract the overlapping part (shown in red) of the blue and the green array from a position `tuple` (the `X` in the image above) like so:

```
blue_overlap, green_overlap = np.extract_overlap(blue_array, green_array, position)
```

The `X` doesn't necessary need to be the center of the green area, it could be a corner cell as well. If the width/height of the green array isn't odd, it would make sense to use a corner cell instead.

As long as the green area is completely within the bounds of the blue area the problem is simple *slicing* based on the position of `X`. But when the green area extends the boundary of the blue area, I need to do adjustments which I feel could already be implemented somehow in `numpy` but I haven't found it.

Does such a method exists?

Comment: What are these two arrays storing? Is each cell a coordinate? It isn't clear how you're defining the position of the green relative to the blue.

Comment: Why not writing it yourself? Just take the component-wise minimum of the coordinates of the lower, right corners and then the component-wise maximum of the upper left corners and you have the corners of the intersection rectangle. From there on its just taking slices.

Comment: @Trilarion, because I have written this myself quite a few times now and I feel I keep *reinventing* the wheel :)

Comment: May I ask where in numpy you have already looked for a method with the signature that you propose or something similar? Numpy is not that big, I think there is a list of all their functions on their website somewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion, well if you post an answer stating that the function I am looking for is not part of the current Numpy implementation, I'll accept that answer. I haven't looked through the entire numpy method list, but all my searches so far hasn't provided me with an answer. Thus my question here, which could also help others looking for something similar.

Comment: @Chau I haven't looked through the numpy method list, so I could not really answer the question.